# How to get id value from database using ajax? .net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have a blog site and I made a comment panel under the article. example; user name, mail adress and comment...

I can add these fields using ajax but can't determine which article the comment is made on.
That's inputs..

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <%-- <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="color: #fff;">Name</label>--%>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="t1" name="name" placeholder="Adınız" required tabindex="1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%-- <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="color: #fff;">E-mail</label>--%>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="t2" name="email" placeholder="E-mail Adresiniz" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%--  <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label" style="color: #fff;">Message</label>--%>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <textarea id="t3" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Yorumunuz" rows="5" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6">
                        <button type="submit" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ekle()">Gönder</button>
                    </div>
```

that's commentAjax.aspx code behind;

```
      sqlBaglantisi baglan = new sqlBaglantisi();
string adsoyad, email, yorum, makaleID;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    makaleID = Request.QueryString["makaleID"];
    adsoyad = Request.QueryString["adsyd"].ToString();
    email = Request.QueryString["em"].ToString();
    yorum = Request.QueryString["yrm"].ToString();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Yorum (yorumAdSoyad, yorumEmail, yorumIcerik, yorumResim, makaleID) values('" + adsoyad.ToString() + "','" + email.ToString() + "','" + yorum.ToString() + "','/tema/yorumm.png')", baglan.baglan());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

and js codes;

```
function ekle() {
var ad = document.getElementById("t1").value;
var mail = document.getElementById("t2").value;
var yorum = document.getElementById("t3").value;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "yorumAjax.aspx?adsyd=" + ad + "&em=" + mail + "&yrm="+yorum, false);
xmlhttp.send(null);

document.getElementById("t1").value = "";
document.getElementById("t2").value = "";
document.getElementById("t3").value = "";


alert("Mesaj Gönderildi");
```

I can't understand which comment has come to which article because I can't get the value of articleID.

Answer (score -1):

You can put a hidden input in your form, containing the actual ID of your article. Something like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="articleID" name="articleID" value="<the id for this article>" />
```

If you are using an MVC architecture, you can define the ID for the article in your view and then pass it to the template when rendering.

```
<input type="hidden" id="articleID" name="articleID" value="{{ article.id }}" />
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" id="articleID" name="articleID" value="{{ id }}" />
```

This way, you can then obtain the value of the article id like you did with the other fields in the javascript function.